# Skype for Linux does not launch itself in the background

Tags: skype

Since version 8.62.0.85 (released July 2020) Skype for Linux does not honor the setting "Launch Skype in the background" under Tools -> Settings -> General. A Skype window always pops up after launch independent of the setting.

[A screenshot of the Skype settings window is found in this Manjaro forum for reference.](https://forum.manjaro.org/t/skype-for-linux/79753)

Comment: Same problem here after upgrading from 8.61.0.95 to 8.62.0.85 in Ubuntu 16.04-base. Seems the problem is common to Windows 10, as described here: https://answers.microsoft.com/it-it/skype/forum/all/skype-non-va-in-background-quando-si-avvia-in/b733aac2-1cf9-4bec-a24c-9fd543af5359 (Italian language).

Comment: Interesting. So reinstalling does not help. I wonder if there is an utility similar to wmctrl under Windows to work around the issue the same way as described below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Update to Skype for Linux 8.64.0.80 or newer to fix this issue.

I could not find the release notes for this version but it solved the issue for me (without using the workaround described in my previous answer).

Answer (score 1):

First make sure that the setting "Upon closing, keep Skype running" is active under Tools -> Settings -> General, otherwise this solution will not work.

Then open `/usr/bin/skypeforlinux` and add the following lines at the end:

```
# Launch Skype in the background
sleep 10
wmctrl -F -c Skype
```

This change must be applied again after each update of Skype since the file `/usr/bin/skypeforlinux` is part of the Skype installation and will be brought back to its original state after each update.

[`wmctrl` interacts with an X Window manager.](https://linux.die.net/man/1/wmctrl) `wmctrl -c` closes a window gracefully. `wmctrl -F` matches the exact, case sensitive window title.

A short wait is needed until the Skype window appears, hence the [`sleep`](https://linux.die.net/man/1/sleep) command. 10 seconds worked for me, other/slower computers may need a longer wait. This is a bit flimsy and there are probably more elegant ways to wait for a window to open but it does the job as a workaround.

The setting "Launch Skype in background" under Tools -> Settings -> General will have no effect. Skype will always start in the background independent of the setting.